# C# how to check for null. (value is null) or (null == value). Can we use `is` operator instead of == operator

Tags: c#, null, nullable, c#-7.0

C# how to check for `null`. `(value is null)` or `(null == value)`. Can we use `is` operator instead of `==` operator?

C# 7.0 supports const pattern with `is` operator. So we can use `is null` for all null checking ?

Can the object be empty as well besides being null?

Comment: We don't you try this by your own? It's not that much work...

Comment: @random: While I agree the OP could check whether or not it works, that wouldn't give as much information about exactly what's going on as we can.

Comment: (While I've closed this as a duplicate now that a more appropriate duplicate has been found, I've left my answer as it does no harm being here.)

Comment: @JonSkeet and you get nice votes for it ;)

Comment: @HimBromBeere: With the rep cap, that won't actually make any rep difference... <sigh>

Comment: Shahid, by empty object, do you possibly mean something like an empty string or empty list?

Comment: @JonSkeet Assuming you hit the cap on every day (which I have no doubt you do).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `is` operator with the constant pattern of `null` to check whether a reference (or nullable value type value) is null or not.

Indeed, in C# 7 I would say that using `is null` is the most *idiomatic* way of testing for a null value, because it doesn't use any user-defined operators. Consider this:

```
string x = GetStringFromSomewhere();

if (x == null) { }  // Option 1
if (x is null) { }  // Option 2
```

Here, option 1 will call the `==` operator overload defined in `string`. While that should do what you want (and I expect the JIT compiler will optimize it pretty heavily), it's not like you particularly *want* to do that - you just want to test whether the value of `x` is a null reference. That's exactly what option 2 does.

So yes, you can use `is null` for all null checking *if* you don't have types that perform odd custom comparisons. It's possible to write a class such that `x == null` and `x is null` would give different results, but that would almost always be a design (or implementation) problem.

There's no concept of an object being "empty" - and indeed it's not the *object* that's null. Leaving nullable value types aside for now, it's a *reference* that's null, not an object - a null value indicates the absence of an object. It's worth distinguishing carefully between objects and references in your mind.

Some specific object types have a concept of "empty" - for example, a string can be empty, or a collection - but those types have specific ways of testing for emptiness. There's no *general* concept of an object being empty.

Comment: I have a feeling that something is lost due to a language barrier...  I think the "empty" concept is referring to something like python, where an empty list returns false {if ([]): //Returns false}

Comment: @Mars: But there's no such concept in C# for a general object. There's the concept of an empty array, or an empty list etc - but you'd need to check for that specifically.

Comment: I know. Just think thats possibly where this question was coming from, even if it wasn't asked very clearly

Comment: @Mars: Have added a paragraph at the end of the answer to help with that.

Comment: Much better than the answer in the linked question.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you please expand a little bit over the phrase **So yes, you can use is null for all null checking if you don't have types that perform odd custom comparisons**. Based on my knowledge a programmer can write an overload of the equality operator (`==`) so that he or she messes up the behavior of the `== null` comparison. How is it possible to write a type such that the behavior of the `is null` comparison breaks ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @EnricoMassone: The point is if you *want* `== null` to sometimes return true for non-null values (a sort of "logical null") then if you change that comparison to `is null`, it won't behave the same way. But if `== null` returns true if and only if the left operand is actually a null reference, just use `is null` instead.